# How to make nano display colors as indicated by color codes?

Tags: colors, nano

I have a Python script that writes a log file "temperatures.csv". Following "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-to-print-colored-text-to-the-terminal", I added some ANSI escape sequences to highlight text when, for example, a temperature reading is above a specified value. The colored text shows nicely wen viewing the log file with `less -R` or `tail` or `cat`. But if I edit the file using `nano`, I see the escape sequence but no color:
`2021-01-18 19:28, ^[[94mRoomTemp: 66.88^[[0m, StoveTemp: 398.3`

Is there a way to get `nano` to interpret ANSI escape sequences and show text in color?
I'm working with Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 Buster and SSH terminals.